# PHP extension: Segmentation fault when returning from a function

Tags: php, c++, c, gdb, php-extension

I am developing a php extension and encounters a problem. In my extension, i defined a function which parse parameters from userspace and pass them to another function in static library.

But when my functions ends, it pops out the following error:
"Cannot access memory at address 0x5
Segmentation fault(core dumped)"

I tried to solve it using gdb and print the following frame information:

```
0x0852dbe3 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (
    execute_data=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffc5>, 
    tsrm_ls=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffc1>) at /home/ted/php-5.5.6/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:550
```

After i type "info frame" command, the following information comes out:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0x9:
 eip = 0x852dbe3 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC
    (/home/ted/php-5.5.6/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:550); saved eip Cannot access memory at address 0x5
```

I have stuck in this for one day.. Could anyone help?

Comment: Crashes when returning from a function typially mean you've overwritten your return address on the stack, which is mostly caused by writing to an out-of-bounds index of an array that's been declared as a local variable. Start a debugger, let your program run until the start of your function, check the back trace. cont to the end of your function and check the back trace again. If there is a difference, then you've overwritten your stack; dumping the memory around the ss:esp address might give you a clue.

Comment: another debugging possibility. Comment out all the lines in the function, execute it, you shouldn't get an error at this time. Introduce the first line, check if the error is reproduced. Progressively add more and more lines until you are able to reproduce this error. By this procedure you should be able to pinpoint to the line which is causing this error.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have added more data that your buffer can take. Examine all array and pointers accoringly

Comment: hi, guys. Thanks a lot for the comments. I have solved the problem as shown in the answer. I suppose this is a rookie mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.. It's caused by a error(maybe) which i don't quite understand. In my php code, i call a function like this:

```
$object->object_function($a,$b,$c,1);
```

In my php extension, i parse all these parameters:

```
if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sral",&string1,&strlen1,&resource,&array1 ,&intVal)     == FAILURE)
```

The problem is, i can't use 1 in php code. Instead, i should use:

```
$d = 1; 
$object->object_function($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

I suppose this is because of my poor understanding of php core. Directly passing 1 into the extension function will actually not give the value i want.